# How to implement a function to create post request in springboot?

Tags: json, spring-boot, api, post, postman

In the Springboot project I'm currently doing,I use Postman client to send post request which includes a JSON body.Following image is relevant to that.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9SJu.png)

```
POST http://localhost:8080/api/v1/orders

Json Body= 
{   
   "fuelType": "Petrol 95",
   "qty": 10000
}
```

Can someone help me how to do this post request(which is in the image) using a function without using postman client.

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/

Answer (score 0):

You can use cURL [(https://curl.se/)](https://curl.se/):

```
curl -X POST 
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
    -d '{"fuelType": "Petrol 95","qty": 10000}'
```

but if you want to make the call from java, you can use any http client from your choice, here is an example using resttemplate :

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
class requestDTO{
   private String fuelType;
   private Integer qty;
}
```

```
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
...
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

HttpEntity<requestDTO> request = new HttpEntity<>(new requestDTO("Petrol 95",10000));
requestDTO output = restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/orders", request, requestDTO.class);
```

Comment: Can you please tell  me how to include this in a java function and call it?

Comment: if you want to make a call from java, you should use an http client

Comment: @ImilaMaheshan I added an example to call api from java